# How fix this problem with shading

Tags: modeling, mesh

I modeling simple shape and I don't know why showing shading transition between circle part and cylinder part of model. The mesh have shade smooth and auto smooth set.
[image]

Comment: Try to add an edge loop just below.

Comment: Adding edge loop not fix the problem and add another transition.

Comment: Add more (3 or 4), regularly spaced below the top half sphere.

Comment: Not too good showing on image but mesh have 2 transition ![Image](https://i.imgur.com/JD8oFH6.jpg)

Comment: Yes but minimized.and should nearly be invisible at rendering.

Comment: It is also possible that you have a little difference of radius between the base and the sphere (if yes, that should accentuate the effect).

Comment: Here is my ![file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UXzFbwxhZ7hZwgCYkQkiHCpxb2a-axq9/view?usp=sharing). Can you check it please?

Comment: Nearly ok https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6302/ Did it playing with edge loops, smooth vertex and adjusting. But this is not a rendering setup, so this is not really signifiant.

Comment: Thank for help, but transition not gone. Yes, I did this too yesterday all day :) but don't happy with final result. Maybe it is limitation of technology?